# Добавить поле к каждому объекту итерируемой коллекции

Tags: python, django

Всем доброго времени суток.

Итак, `Python`. Есть коллекция объектов, по которой можно пройтись циклом. Последнее время часто возникает потребность к каждому объекту коллекции добавить переменную, которая вычисляется, например, методом этого же объекта, который не имеет побочных эффектов. Я делаю так.

Класс, например, такой:

```
class myClass:
    x = 5
    y = 6

    def get_zet(self):
        return self.x + self.y
```

Создается коллекция из объектов этого класса "set_of_obj".

А потом где-то в коде добавляю поле "zet":

```
for obj in set_of_obj:
    obj.zet = obj.get_zet()
```

Каким образом можно сделать это более элегантно? В функциональном стиле, например.

Comment: Я один не понял зачем нужно свойство, если есть метод?

Или я просто не проникся всей глубиной идеи?

Аж интересно стало, может приведете пример конкретного использования?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В функциональном стиле это можно было бы записать так:

```
set_of_obj = map(lambda x: x.__setattr__('zet', x.get_zet()) or x, set_of_obj)
```

Не слишком элегантно. Ваш вариант понятнее.

Answer (score 2):

Если x и y не изменяются, то создавайте поле при инициализации класса. Если меняются, то поле не нужно - используйте метод для получения значения.

Answer (score 1):

```
for obj in set_of_obj:
    obj.__setattr__('zet', obj.get_zet())
```

ИМХО, хотя предложенный Вами способ достаточно элегантен.